# Error while converting jar to dll using IKVM

Tags: java, asp.net, ikvm

I had created a library project in android. This library project selects the real path of the image from gallery. I want to reference this application in asp.net. So, i converted it in dll using ikvm, But there was a warning that "".

the code follows below.

```
public String BrowseImageFromGallery(){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    if(imageRealPath != null)
    {
        return imageRealPath;
    }
    return null;
}

public String TakeImageFromCamera(){

    TakeImage();
    return imageRealPath;
}

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent ){

    switch (resultCode){

    case GALLERY_REQUEST : {
        selectedImageUri = intent.getData();
        imageRealPath = GetRealPathFromUri(selectedImageUri);
    }
    break;

    case CAMERA_REQUEST : {
        imageRealPath = GetRealPathFromUri(selectedImageUri);
    }
    break;
    }

}

private String GetRealPathFromUri(Uri imageUri) {

    try
    {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(imageUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_Index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_Index);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return imageUri.getPath();
    }
}

private void TakeImage() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     imageName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, imageName);
    selectedImageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

}
```

}

the problem is due to the fact that i am extending Activity class and it is not referencing when i am converting it to the dll. So, I add the reference of  android.jar. Everything working fine, But when i run the program there was error.

To check what is the i made a simple add method in the java library and called it from c# code on button click. The error follows below

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

IKVM is for Java SE. You can only use API of the Java SE or of third party. Your Android.jar is only a stup jar file for the compiler. At runtime it contains native calls to the Android Java VM.

Create your own stub android.app.Activity and not the Android.jar. Your stub should call only API of the standard Java API.

Comment: Which type of help do you need?. Remove all references in your android project to Android. For example the android.jar. Add a reference to a second project. For example with the Name AndroidStub. Add in this project classes and methods until the compiler error disappear. Compile both project with IKVM.